# Security question for skin change always fails

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I try to change my skin, it asks me to answer a security question. I answer them correctly, yet it says that they are incorrect. Why?

Comment: it doesn't let me change the questions either

Answer (score 5):

Security questions are possibly my most hated security feature for anything online, and the reason is because they are computer-processed. Computers are actually quite dumb, and can only follow precise orders. So unless you enter the answer **exactly as you first gave it**, you will automatically fail.

To give the best example, I attended Saint Josephs for primary education, up the road from where I live, in Moorebank, New South Wales.

Luckily, this was not the first school I attended. If asked to give my first primary school for a security question, I could easily have many answers:

- St. Josephs Moorebank
- St. Josephs, Moorebank
- St Josephs, Moorebank
- Saint Josephs, Moorebank
- Saint Josephs Catholic School
- Saint Joseph's Primary
- Saint Josephs Catholic Primary School

I think I have made my point. But **you have to match the original response exactly**, including the capital letters, the spelling, and all punctuation.

Comment: And of course,  someone can just go on Facebook or whatever and find some answers...

Comment: As an anecdote to that, facebook asks you some of the same questions to fill out your profile as it does to set security questions.